# Pass a variable from Page1 to Page2

Tags: php

// Page 1 - Code below works fine, but when I click the href link the
// variable I want is not sent to page 2.

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<tr>
            <td><a href="recipe_show.php?recipe_name=recipe_name"> ' . $row['recipe_name'] . ' </a></td>    
        </tr>';
    $recipe_name = $row['recipe_name']; 
    }
$_SESSION['recipe_name'] = $recipe_name;
    echo '</table>'; // Close the table
?>

// Page2 - Code below receives the variable from page 1, but only the    //last one in the table and not the one I clicked. 
include ('core/init.php'); // Connect to the database
$recipe_name = $_SESSION['recipe_name'];
    echo "My recipes is: ".$recipe_name."<br>";
 ?>
```

Comment: Can you use session_start(); for each page?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this using a get request.Since the users can see/alter the data, this is not the safest way of doing this but will do the job. Sessions are not involved in this technique.

```
<?php
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
       echo '<tr><td>
             <a href="recipe_show.php?recipe_name='.$row['recipe_name'].'"> ' . $row['recipe_name'] . ' </a></td></tr>'; 
    }
    echo '</table>';
?>
```

// Page2

```
 <?php
    $recipe_name = $_GET['recipe_name'];
    echo "My recipes is: ".$recipe_name."<br>";
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong in your page 2

Instead of session use $_GET['']; To get value from url we use $_GET.

Like this:

```
$recipe_name = $_GET['recipe_name'];
```

I hope this would help you.

Comment: The info given worked like a charm. Much appreciate your input. Having coded with Visual Basic for the last 20 years PHP, CSS etc. not so easy, again, thanks